# (php) Looping table header using data from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to loop the data from database into the table header which these are my codes so far.

```
<table name="Score_Filtering" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Lastname</th>   

<?php 

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
?>
<th><?php echo $rowss['Skill_Name'] ?> Score</th>
<?php 
}
?>

<th>Overall Score</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>View Information</th>

</tr>

</table>
```

Assume that "$rowss" has been declared with

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
 $rowss = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Which the table are turned out ok as I want except...

```
 <th><?php echo $rowss['Skill_Name'] ?> Score</th>
```

This part only show "Score" on the header but without the data from database which I want it to be inserted in front of "Score".

Any suggestions on how to do this or guide me in the right direction.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_` functions but mysqli or PDO instead, they are deprecated and can't be used since PHP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not use `mysql_*` functions as they deprecated and are completely removed in PHP 7.

Back to your problem, you are getting multiple rows from database, so, use while loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 // Your code
}
```